# Web Components inside React app

Tags: reactjs, polymer, create-react-app

I'm using some custom made Web Components made on top of Polymer in my react app(created using Create-react-app).
Until now I was loading the components using

```
<link rel="import" href="URL of a git ">
```

and it worked fine. 
But I'm getting a warning from Google Chrome :

```
[Deprecation] Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML 
Imports is deprecated, and is planned to be removed in M65, around March 
2018. Please refer to  for possible migration paths.
```

So I tried installing them using bower but I cannot find a way to import them correctly. 
I Tried :

```
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/....">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/....">
```

Now that the files are in bower_components directory how can I use them inside my react app ? I saw that some react extension existed but I didn't see how I could use these customs components.

Thank you for your help,